# Getting the right values of attributes of an xml file

Tags: xml, parsing, ocaml

I'm using Xml_Light to parse an xml file with ocaml.
I have string attribute values that contains character like '<','>','|'.
My problem is When I get these values and when I print them, I get these html names <> and not the original character.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put the characters `<` and `>` in a xml file (except of course to write tags), use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead.

Comment: I extract strings containing '<' and '>' and i put them into the xml file. So, i have to get these values.

Comment: Characters `<`, `&` (and `>` in some cases) are forbidden in the text (everything that is not markup) of an XML file, you MUST escape them. Read the spec : http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#syntax